# App crashes when pulling down notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, control-center

My app crashes when pulling down the notifications or bottom bar with all the modes (Music, BT, Brightness etc. I do not remember what its called). The crash happens in all the pages of the app.

The error is:

```
2014-12-15 15:09:09.738 IRR[734:58765] -[ProjectsMain applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17575b50
2014-12-15 15:09:09.740 IRR[734:58765] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ProjectsMain applicationDidBecomeActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17575b50'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x236855f7 0x311d3c77 0x2368aabd 0x23688999 0x235b9b88 0x2363df15 0x23598e4d 0x242cdec1 0x26ba65b9 0x26d96099 0x26d8dded 0x29dd40c9 0x2364bffd 0x2364b2c1 0x23649e1b 0x23596b31 0x23596943 0x2a94d051 0x26b8c6f1 0x445b9 0x3176faaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What kind of object it `ProjectsMain`?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have manually called `applicationDidBecomeActive` ?

Comment: Yep, I use applicationDidBecomeActive. Poked around lite bit with that and the problem solved!

Please post is answer!